# Bluetooth reporting "not enough handles available to register service"

Tags: debian, bluetooth, bluez, blueman

Running `BlueZ 5.36` on `Debian Testing`. Pairing, and connecting, to a Bluetooth audio sink fails, and, as [previously reported](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=813949) subsequently logs (several times over)

```
Oct 12 09:16:51 0x44 bluetoothd[1878]: Not enough free handles to register service
```

1. Restarting the `bluetoothd` service doesn't resolve the issue
2. Removing, and later re-pairing the device (through blueman-manager gui) doesn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a hacky "solution", at best, but I managed to get the device connected by

```
# bluetoothctl
[bluetooth] remove <device>
[bluetooth] power off
[bluetooth] power on
[bluetooth] scan
[bluetooth] pair <device>
[bluetooth] trust <device>
[bluetooth] connect <device>
```

Note that I tried the remove/scan/pair/connect routine without powering on/off a couple of times, without success, so that might be key.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here with Mint 18.2 Cinnamon and HID Logitech Mouse M535.
No matter which Kernel I used (from 4.8-x to 4.13.0-17) the same issue occured again.

After excessive looking at power saving options, browsing of system logs and bug reporting forums, the only solution i found working, was:

> $ sudo bluetoothctl
>
> power off
>
> power on
>
> quit

After that, while running bluewho besides blueman, I finally managed to pair the frickin thing again.

Hope it lasts.